# Multitenancy in hbase

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

Can you please suggest how can I use Multitenancy in HBase.I was searching it but cannot get proper information. Please post some information related to the subject.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean building a multi-tenant application in a single cluster?  Do you mean provisioning a single HBase cluster with multiple users?

Comment: yes @SolomonDuskis

Comment: There are two options... Are you building an application, or are you creating infrastructure for developers?

Comment: Hello @SolomonDuskis  we have an application where we use hbase as our main database.In future we need to implement multitenancy for this that's why I need help regarding this